# How to update HREF on swatch click

Tags: configurable-product, configurable-swatches

I am wanting to try and find out how to set up configurable products to where the color swatches are linked to simple products but beyond that how we can have the HREF be updated as well as the description and product name in the address bar when each swatch is clicked on. See example below of what we're attempting to emulate:

https://www.braun-hamburg.com/en/von-braun-cashmere-knit-blazer-light-grey.html#

Example:

If 'blue' is selected 'Blue' is then dynamically added to product title, is referenced in URL and the description notes content as it relates to that 'blue' product.